# Update management of large clusters of Ubuntu servers

Tags: ubuntu, updates, package-management, apt, automatic-update

is there any software that may be used for managing updates on group of Ubuntu machines? I would like to let some test machines get updated with all available ubuntu updates, then test the resulting systems and (after possibly a few days or even week) update the production machines with the same packages tested.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt

https://www.infoworld.com/article/2609482/data-center-review-puppet-vs-chef-vs-ansible-vs-salt.html

All they can solve the problem. Personally, I tried ansible and puppet. Personally, I liked the ansible more. My first training playbook was updating remote servers.

While Puppet and Chef are developer-oriented, Salt and Ansible are more suited to the needs of system administrators. Simple interface and usability Ansible suits the thinking of system administrators in companies with a large number of Unix and Linux systems.

In truth, this is one of Ansible's coolest qualities - you can study it in one evening and already start the web server from YAML or receive updates on a remote computer. Ansible tasks are run sequentially, which greatly facilitates troubleshoot configurations. Ansible written in python. If we take 10 programmers, the probability that one of them knows Python is much higher than that one of them knows Ruby. This is what makes Ansible cool - it is written in python unlike Ruby - based competitors. I also note that the Python library is usually present by default in any Linux distribution, which is not the case with Ruby. Ansible supports writing modules in any programming language. The only requirement is the response format. It must be JSON.**No need to install agent software on remote machines - only an SSH connection.**

Comment: I used ansible once, but it seems more related to automate operations. At least, it lacks the package repository management (I need to freeze the repository used for updating test machines and, later on, update production machines from the very same repository).

Comment: Maybe a puppet is better for you. The configuration of all systems is stored on the management server in the form of text files called manifests or recipes. They can be organized using a special directory structure into modules. Typically, each module is responsible for setting up a single component or service.

Comment: Managed systems are connected to the manager, which collects all configuration items in a directory that is transferred to the connected system. Having received the catalog, the managed system starts comparing its current state with the state described in the catalog, and makes decisions about what actions should be performed to bring the current state to the transferred control system.